# How to use ~のか accurately? 「体調が悪いのか、顔色があまり良くない。」

Tags: grammar

Can anyone explain to me the function of のか in this sentence? Is it "I suppose that..." or similar?

> 彼は、体調が悪い**のか**、顔色があまり良くない。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 「彼{かれ}は、体調{たいちょう}が悪{わる}い**のか**、顔色{かおいろ}があまり良{よ}くない。」

When used mid-sentence like that, 「のか」 ***questions*** the preceding statement to some extent.  For  translation purposes, one might use:

> "***Not sure whether*** [preceding statement] ***is the case, but ~~~~~***."
>
> "***Not sure if it is because*** [preceding statement], ***but ~~~~~***."

In the sentence in question, 「体調が悪い」 is only a speculation whereas 「顔色があまり良くない」 is a fact.  That is why the speaker/writer uses 「のか」 to express the ***possibility*** of the preceding statement not being totally correct.

In this sentence, 「のか」 can be replaced by 「からなのか」 or 「せいなのか」 without changing the meaning.

Comment: Is this a の of nominalization then?