# What does のか mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-か

In this sentence:

> ドアの音に驚いた**のか**、軽く上体がかしいだ

a door opens, and there is a character, whose upper body is slightly bent forward, startled by the door's sound.

I think `の` just nominalize `ドアの音に驚いた`, but I'm not sure about `か`: I don't think is the embedded question-か, given how it goes on (`軽く上体がかしいだ`), and I can't think an use of `か` I know of that suits this sentence.

Since as far as I know `か` can also be used to express doubt I was wondering if it's something like "**Maybe due** to being startled by the door's sound, [she had her] upper body slightly bent forward", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60298/9831

Comment: Yes, I'd say duplicate; thanks for the link, I totally missed that while looking for answers, feel free to tag this as duplicate.