# What does ～の為か mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, parsing, particle-か

> ちょうど昼過ぎの為か、よく空いていた車内。

[According to Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%BA), 為 means "sake; purpose", "consequence; result", "regarding, concerning", but I can't say what meaning is in this sentence, and also I don't know what is the meaning of か in this case. I know that [か can make a question as a relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/usage-of-%E3%81%8B-after-a-clause), but I'm not sure if it is the case here, and if so, I don't understand the relationship of the first clause with か and the following sentence.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65697/5010

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60298/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we remove か from the sentence we get 「ちょうど昼過ぎの為、よく空いていた車内。」'a car that was very empty, because it was just after noon'. The か here removes some amount of certainty, almost like saying '*perhaps* because it was just after noon'.

Comment: Maybe it`s helpful for someone who's reading this later: in the Jisho definitions, the [4th definition](https://jisho.org/word/か) is "hmm; huh​ (indicates doubt, uncertainty, etc.)"